# If I add a delay in a daemon initialization, may it affect how other daemons are loaded at boot time?

Tags: c++, linux, daemon

I have developed a daemon in C++ whose main code is the following:

```
if ((ret = daemonize(daemonpath, daemonpid)) == -1) {
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Ejecutando daemon");

    Reader reader(bSearch);
    reader.StartAsync();
    while (!exitdaemon) {

    }
    reader.StopAsync();
    daemonShutdown();
}
```

"daemonize" method does all the stuff to create the daemon (does a fork, creates the PID, etc.) so it is not relevant for the question because it is the standard code to create a daemon.

Well, the daemon works perfectly, but when I configure the system to load my daemon at boot time, it enteres in conflict with other daemon. The fact is that the other daemon initializes some hardware my daemon uses. So, I need to start my daemon some seconds later than the other daemon.

If I add a `usleep(5000000)` call after the `if` statement, may it affect the delay of the other daemons in the system?

I think it should not affect because the "daemonize" method does a fork, so a copy of this process is launched, and the rest of the main process continues normally after the "if" statement.

Can you confirm if this is true?

Comment: `daemonize()` will prevent your daemon from holding up other processes, but there's no guarantee that a hard-coded delay of 5000000 (or any amount, really) will be long enough to ensure that the hardware is initialized properly before you try to use it.  You'd be better off trying to use the hardware immediately, and then if you find that you can't (because the hardware is uninitialized), *that* would be the time to sleep for a second or two and then try again (and repeat as necessary until the hardware is usable).

Comment: If your daemon is a service, why not set the other daemon as a dependency so that it doesn't start up until the other one is up?

Not sure if this is applicable to your case, but there is something [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/617823/how-to-set-systemd-service-dependencies) that may be useful for your case.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner. I understand your point and you are right. However, the actual problem is that both daemons tries to use the hardware at the same time, causing it to get blocked. When that happens, once in SSH console, I need to shutdown my daemon... then the hardware is unblocked. By the way, this is not a computer but an RFID antenna, and what I have watched, with 5 seconds is enough to wait. That is why I asked if I add the delay after the if, the forked process willl wait, but the main process will return so, all other daemons should start without that delay.

Comment: @LarryB I have seen I can add the service in the sh script, in the line "# Required-Start:    $local_fs $syslog"... but, how can I get the other daemon name? is the name of the sh file used to start it?

Comment: Does your daemon access the hardware via files on the file system? If yes, then you might be able to use `lsof` to figure out which process is accessing those files.